# Type conflicts with Event Listeners

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I am trying to attach an event handler to a DOM node using Fable:

```
let handleIntroSubmit (event: Event) = ()

container
    .querySelector("#some-node")
    .addEventListener("click", handleIntroSubmit)
```

However this fails with following error:

[image]

This error is baffling for me because:

Looking at the source of [Fable.Import.Browser](https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-import/blob/master/Browser/Fable.Import.Browser.fs) I find `EventListenerOrEventListenerObject` [defined](https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-import/blob/master/Browser/Fable.Import.Browser.fs#L11012) as such:

```
EventListenerOrEventListenerObject =
    U2<EventListener, EventListenerObject>
```

And `EventListener` [defined](https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-import/blob/master/Browser/Fable.Import.Browser.fs#L172) as such:

```
EventListener = (Event -> unit)
```

Looking at this definition I would have assumed that `handleIntroSubmit` would be compatible with `EventListener` and therefore with the union type `EventListenerOrEventListenerObject` ?

However, to my surprise I discovered that it isn't actually compatible with `EventListener`, even though their signatures would seem identical to me. When I try the following:

```
let listener: EventListener = handleIntroSubmit
```

I get following error:

```
This expression was expected to have type
    'EventListener'    
but here has type
    ''a -> unit'
```

This error makes no sense to me, in particular I have no idea where does the `'a` generic type comes from despite the fact that I have provided an explict type annotation for function `handleIntroSubmit` argument.

I would ideally like to know why the above does not work, what the error means here and what is the best/typesafe (without unbox) way to add event listener using Fable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate issues here.

**Firstly,** the definition of `EventListener` that you linked [only appeared in `master` two days ago](https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-import/commit/db7e40d78fd62926e11e8220c882c596efe1152d#diff-434cfab899cfc40a17547bc9ef6ae86cL170). Before that, the definition was `Func<Event, unit>`, which is a .NET delegate, and not at all the same as F# function `Event -> unit`. From the error message, it is apparent that you're using an earlier version of the library.

To fix this, redefine your function like this:

```
let handleIntroSubmit = Func<Event, unit>( fun e -> () )
```

This will give it the type of `Func<Event, unit>`, which is what `EventListener` is (currently).

**Secondly,** even if `handleIntroSubmit` is compatible with `EventListener`, it does not mean that it will also be compatible with `U2<EventListener, _>`. That's a whole different type, why would it be compatible?

To produce a value of `U2<EventListener, _>` from a value of `EventListener`, use the [first constructor of the `U2` union - `Case1`](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/blob/master/src/dotnet/Fable.Core/Fable.Core.fs#L65):

```
let listener: U2<EventListener, EventListenerObject> = Case1 handleIntroSubmit
```

Of course, writing `Case1` every time is a bit tedious. Thankfully, for dealing with such cases, Fable's core library provides [a handy operator `!^`](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/blob/0167c8bf5b12dee01267453cecc1704fa5e76d5f/src/dotnet/Fable.Core/Fable.Core.JsInterop.fs#L12):

```
let listener: U2<EventListener, EventListenerObject> = !^handleIntroSubmit
```

Comment: I am marking this as accepted as this answer provides a much better description than https://stackoverflow.com/a/48389151/476712 though all the above information was available in the linked discussion.

Comment: > That a whole different type, why would it be compatible?

-- When I wrote the question I did not know that F# 's union types were not similar to Typescript/Flow union types.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant [discussion](https://gitter.im/fable-compiler/Fable?at=5a662a7fae53c159031e4210) on Fable's gitter.

It was resolved in the  [solution](https://gitter.im/fable-compiler/Fable?at=5a663c9e0ad3e04b1b553f3d) provided by Maxime Mangel - [relevant fiddle](http://fable.io/repl/#?code=open%20Fable.Core%0Aopen%20Fable.Core.JsInterop%0Aopen%20Fable.Import.Browser%0Aopen%20System%0A%0Alet%20btn%20%3D%20document.querySelector(%22.btn%22)%20%3A%3F%3E%20HTMLButtonElement%0A%0Abtn.addEventListener_click(fun%20_%20-%3E%20console.log%20%22clicked%22%3B%20null)%0A%0Abtn.addEventListener(%22click%22%2C%20!%5E(Func%3C_%2C_%3E(fun%20_%20-%3E%20console.log%20%22clicked2%22)))%0A&html=%3Chtml%3E%0A%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20http-equiv%3D%22Content-Type%22%20content%3D%22text%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%22%3E%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20class%3D%22btn%22%3EClick%20me%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E%0A).

```
btn.addEventListener("click", !^(Func<_,_>(fun _ -> console.log "clicked2")))
```